# RoR. Count the numbers of "No", "Yes" and "Does not apply" in an object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form with a checklist for a vehicle (tires ok?, lights ok?, etc)
As an Answer they only have 3 options "Yes","No" and "Does not apply", I need to count the number of "Yes", the number of "No" and the number of "Does not apply" in the object and display in the show

In the show if I put `<%= @equipo %>` i got  `<Equipo:0x00007f96922c1160>`

in the controller if i put

```
@test = Equipo.where(created_at: @equipo.created_at).map { |e| e }
```

and in the show `<%= @test %>` give me something like this

```
[#<Equipo id: 1, nombre: "OL09", c1: "No", c2: "No", c3: "Yes", c4: "Yes", c5: "Does not apply", comments: "adsljadl", created_at: "2020-07-24 18:41:58", updated_at: "2020-07-24 18:41:58">]
```

If i put map directly in `@equipo` give me no method error

Comment: See [these instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow/51145#:~:text=6%20Answers&text=If%20you%20post%20code%20or,format%20and%20syntax%20highlight%20it.&text=Or%20for%20block%20code%2C%20you,%22it%20works!%22) for formatting code on SO.

Comment: You have multiple columns holding "yes", "no" values, to which of those do you refer? All of them?

Comment: Like display at in the show how many answer are "No", how many "Yes" ,etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select only those columns that can take the three mentioned values and return an array with their values. You can flatten that and count the number of occurrences in the array:

```
Equipo
  .where(created_at: @equipo.created_at)
  .pluck(:c1, :c2, :c3, :c4, :c5)
  .flatten
  .group_by(&:itself)
  .transform_values(&:count)
# {"No"=>2, "Yes"=>2, "Does not apply"=>1}
```

There are different ways to count the elements in an array, if your Ruby version allows you, you can use [`Enumerable#tally`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally).

Comment: Thanks! then to display in the view i have to put
No <%= @test["No"] %> times

Comment: That's it @Poluxland. You need a way to know what's how many times, I thought a hash is a good way.